# Commuting elements in $S_4$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I am trying to find out which elements of the permutation group $S_4$ commute with the permutation $(12)(34)$. I am trying to find a way to do this without writing out the group table, and I think Lagrange's theorem is one way to do it, but I cannot figure out how.

Certainly the identity permutation commutes with $(12)(34)$, as does the identity. The inverse map $(34)(12)$ also must commute with $(12)(34)$. I cannot figure out how to determine whether there are any more.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So you are looking for permutations $\sigma\in S_4$ such that $\sigma (12)(34)\sigma^{-1}=(12)(34)$? You should know that
$\sigma (12)(34)\sigma^{-1}=(\sigma(1)\sigma(2))(\sigma(3)\sigma(4))$, and use that. FYI (adding words and terms to your dictionary of mathematical English, the standard term for *interchangeable* is *commutes*, and you are asking about the *centralizer of* $(12)(34)$ = the subgroup of elements that commute with $(12)(34)$.

Comment: The trick really is to understand, what you require from $\sigma$ for the identity
$$(12)(34)=(\sigma(1)\sigma(2))(\sigma(3)\sigma(4))$$
to hold. As there are two disjoint 2-cycles, there are more possibilities than what is immediately obvious.

Comment: (34)(12) is the same as (12)(34). (It is also the inverse of that element, but it feels odd to write it 'backwards'.)

Comment: What about $(12)$ or $(34)$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** You need $\sigma\in S_4$ such that

$$\sigma(12)(34)\sigma^{-1}=(12)(34).$$

Do you know of a handy lemma to evaluate the LHS?

> **Lemma:** For $\rho, \tau\in S_n$ such that $\tau=(t_{1}\dots t_{s_1})\dots (t_k\dots t_{s_k})$, we have $$\rho\tau\rho^{-1}=(\rho(t_{1})\dots \rho(t_{s_1}))\dots (\rho(t_k)\dots \rho(t_{s_k})),$$ where $\rho(x)$ is $\rho$ evaluated at $x$.

Comment: I recognize the conjugacy, but I'm not sure of the lemma you're referring to.

Comment: I've added a spoiler, @MathGuySam.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\size}[1]{\lvert #1 \rvert}$It is useful to know in advance how many elements are you looking for. For this you can use the orbit-stabilizer theorem, which in this case tells you that
$$
24 = \size{S_{4}} = \size{A} \cdot \size{C_{S_{4}}((12)(34))}.
$$
Here $A$ is the conjugacy class of $(12)(34)$, which consists of all elements with the same cyclic structure (product of two distinct $2$-cycles), of which there are 
$$
\frac{\dfrac{4 \cdot 3}{2} \cdot \dfrac{2 \cdot 1}{2}}{2} = 3.
$$

You are interested in the centralizer, which you now know has order $8$. If you have done Sylow's theorems, you see that $C_{S_{4}}((12)(34))$ is a Sylow $2$-subgroup in which $(12)(34)$ is in the centre, and this should help you in finding it.

Then it might be that you have to do this in an elementary way, without using this machinery, and then my answer does not apply - let me know in case, and I will remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You need : $(\sigma(1)\ \sigma(2))(\sigma(3)\ \sigma(4)) = (1\ 2)(3\ 4)$

Using this just go over all possible values of $\sigma$ and you will get :

$\{  e,(1\ 2),(3\ 4),(1\ 2)(3\ 4),(1\ 3\ 2\ 4),(1\ 3)(2\ 4),(1\ 4\ 2\ 3),(1\ 4)(2\ 3) \}$